# How can I fix the 'invalid_request' error when authenticating with Xero API in PowerAutomate?

Tags: xero-api

I am trying to create an API call to Xero following this guide [here](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/client-credentials)

[image]

As far as I understand I need to pass in a base64encoded string version of my clientID and ClientSecret. This is how my power automate Http request looks like

[image]

But when I test it. I get an {"error":"invalid_request"}

I'm expecting to get a success response and get the access_token.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Are you sure you actually base64encoded your client_id and client_secret? You need to do that before passing the string into the Authorization header.

Comment: @AdamDS Thank you for your reply. What I did was go to this site [link](https://www.base64encode.org/)  

I then converted the clientId and ClientSecret there before I sent it to the Authorization header.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad this was a case of carelessness on my part. I had to include the semicolon during the conversion to base64 string